How to list most used topics
I want to list the most used topics by input/output of messages. How can I do this? I'm trying with sum delta but it isn't what I want
sum(delta(kafka_consumergroup_current_offset{})) by (topic, consumergroup)


Consumer offsets always are increasing, and not all consumers use groups. That's not really indicative of most used topics... Something like incoming+outgoing byte rate from the brokers would show that better - check JMX metrics from the broker rather than any consumer group exporter
